# Why is the last line printed twice?

Tags: ruby

When I run this method, the last line where the birth year is given is printed twice.

```
def birth_year
  p "Give me a name, any name!"
  name = gets.chomp.capitalize
  p "Now, how old is #{name}?"
  age = gets.chomp.to_i
  p "#{name} was born in #{2015 - age}!"
end
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling the method? I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The code running without an error means that there is nothing wrong with your syntax. However, calling `chomp` prior to `to_i` is redundant and is a bad practice.

Perhaps you are calling this method in irb. The first printing of the last line is the side effect of the last `p` in your code. The second one is the return value of your code printed by irb.